# How to refer to multiple adjacent cells

Tags: excel, count, cell, countif

I have a work sheet in which there are several cells with a specific entry - let's say "A". These are not all in the same rows/columns. After each cell is a date.
I need to count the number of cells containing "A" which also have a specific date in the cell immediately to its right. I've tried combinations of Countifs and Indirect, with no success. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried combining the two columns with data you are searching for into one hidden column and running Countifs and/or Indirect on that?

Answer (score 2):

This counts the number of times that there is `A` in column A and 1 in column `B`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$5="A")*($B$1:$B$5=1))
```

This outputs in cell `D1`

[image]

Comment: This would not work in my situation as I would have to analyse a whole spreadsheet.

Comment: You just need to amend the ranges

Comment: i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$F$5="A")*($B$1:$G$1=1))` it can take a 2D range but for it to work the second range needs to be offset by 1

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult.

I have created a sample sheet with 8 rows and 5 columns of data.

See below, the formula in cell C12 counts the number of occurrences where the a cell with a date of October 31, 2017 is directly to the right of a cell that contains the text `A`.

[image]

If you want more info as to how this works, read on:

When searching for cells that contain `A`, you don't search in the last column of the data (in this case, column E) because it is impossible for a column to the right to have any date in it. This is why a portion of the formula says `A1:D8="A"` instead of `A1:E8="A"`. This is the same reasoning why we start searching for a date in column B rather than column A in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a helper row. Add additional row on top of your Worksheet. In cell `"A1"` enter formula below.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A2000,"A",B2:B2000,"YourDate")
```

Drag this formula to the rightmost of where you have data, then simply sum all values returned by formula.